# Why does C++11 allow you to declare a local variable as thread_local?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, standards

```
int main()
{
    thread_local int n;
}
```

The code above is legal in C++11.

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration):

> The `thread_local` keyword is only allowed for objects declared at
>   namespace scope, **objects declared at block scope**, and static data
>   members.

I just wonder:

A local variable is always on the current thread's stack, so it's always thread-local. `thread_local int n;` is completely identical to `int n;` in such contexts.

Why does C++11 allow to declare a local variable as `thread_local`, rather than **explicitly disable it** to avoid abuse?

Comment: Being local doesn't imply automatic storage duration. In fact, `thread_local` defines a new storage duration for it, just like `static`.

Comment: "Being local doesn't imply automatic storage duration.", Any example?

Comment: `void foo() { static int s; }` - `s` is not destroyed until the end of the program, assuming `foo` is called so that `s` is created. It is not put on a function's stack frame - that would destroy it too early. `thread_local` is an alternative storage duration to `static` or the **implicit** automatic duration. Just because it's the implicit one doesn't mean it's always that one - you can be explicit and change it, for example, to thread-local. I'm using `static` because it's likely to be more familiar. You can mostly think of `thread_local` the same way, but per thread instead of global.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the standard, a `thread_local` variable at block scope is also implicitly `static`.    However, not all `static` variables are `thread_local`.

So

```
 int main()
 {
       thread_local int x;
 }
```

is actually equivalent to

```
 int main()
 {
       thread_local static int x;
 }
```

but different from;

```
 int main()
 {
       int x;    //  auto implied
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that stack variables are thread local.

The `thread_local` keywork is intended to apply only to variables of global or static scope. Normally a single instance of these variables are created at program (or dll/so) load time. thread_local makes separate instances of these global variables for each thread.

The probable reason for not being the default is that this is new behavior not present in C++03. Also, depending on ABI, a kernel call may be needed to access a thread_local variable which is slow, so only done when really needed.

Comment: "Stack variables" have automatic storage duration. A `thread_local` object can't be on the stack, as its lifetime lasts until the thread terminates. It's more of a thread-specific static object.

Comment: Which automatically results in different instances for different threads.

Comment: `thread_local` isn't only about there being separate instances, but also about the lifetime of the object. "A variable with thread storage duration shall be initialized before its first odr-use and, if constructed,
shall be destroyed on thread exit." (§ 3.7.2); "When `thread_local` is applied to a variable of block scope the *storage-class-specifier* `static` is implied if it does not appear explicitly." (§ 7.1.1)